# selenium firefox 52.0.2 along with intellij idea is crashing

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, intellij-idea, selenium-webdriver

I'm using IntelliJ and selenium to automate a very simple test case but It's crashing in the beginning itself.

Also, I tried changing the firefox browser to `46` but it still opens `52.0.2` and crashes.

Questions:
 - ***How can I get it to work?***
 - ***How can I change the default browser firefox browser to 46 and not 52.0.2 on Mac?***

***Code snippet***:

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.*;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;

import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class tt {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private String baseUrl;
    private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
    private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        baseUrl = "https://github.com";
        loadFirefoxDriver();
        //loadChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    private void loadFirefoxDriver() {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }

    private void loadChromeDriver() throws MalformedURLException {
        // To remove message "You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --ignore-certificate-errors.
        // Stability and security will suffer."
        // Add an argument 'test-type'
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("test-type");
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:9515"), capabilities);
    }

    @Test
    public void testFirstSelenium() throws Exception {
        driver.get(baseUrl + "/codesolid");
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("tutorials")).click();
        assertEquals("Welcome to the CodeSolid Tutorials", driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("html body.logged_out.env-production.windows.vis-public div.wrapper div.site div.container div.repository-with-sidebar.repo-container.new-discussion-timeline.js-new-discussion-timeline.with-full-navigation div#js-repo-pjax-container.repository-content.context-loader-container div#readme.clearfix.announce.instapaper_body.md article.markdown-body.entry-content h1")).getText());
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
        String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
        if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
            fail(verificationErrorString);
        }
    }

    private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
        try {
            driver.findElement(by);
            return true;
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private boolean isAlertPresent() {
        try {
            driver.switchTo().alert();
            return true;
        } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private String closeAlertAndGetItsText() {
        try {
            Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
            String alertText = alert.getText();
            if (acceptNextAlert) {
                alert.accept();
            } else {
                alert.dismiss();
            }
            return alertText;
        } finally {
            acceptNextAlert = true;
        }
    }
}
```

***Gradle***:

```
/*
    build.gradle file for building and running Selenium tests
    Example uses:
    gradle clean test       - Rebuild and run tests
    gradle test             - Run tests only
    gradle cleanTest test   - Force tests to be run even if up to date
    gradle viewResults      - Displays the report of test results (Windows only)
*/

// Support for building and testing
apply plugin: 'java'

// (Optional) configure name and version for jar
jar {
    version  '1.0'
    baseName 'SeleniumStarter'
    extension '.jar'
}

// Cf. Maven properties
ext.junitVersion = '4.11'
ext.seleniumVersion = '2.41.0'


// Cf. Maven <dependencies>
dependencies {
    compile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: junitVersion
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-firefox-driver', version:seleniumVersion
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-chrome-driver', version:seleniumVersion
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-api', version:seleniumVersion
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version:seleniumVersion
}

// A custom task to show report on tests that have run
task viewResults(dependsOn: ['test'] , type:Exec) {
    workingDir './build/reports/tests'
    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'start index.html'
}

// Resolve Maven dependencies as Maven does
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}
```

***Error stacktrace***:

```
1490969272079   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:14563
1490969272652   mozprofile::profile INFO    Using profile path /var/folders/hd/4pn57v5x75b81hdv1nrg7tlw0000gq/T/rust_mozprofile.YiFu7gXew5Bk
1490969272655   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin with args []
1490969272668   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Connecting to Marionette on localhost:59730
1490969273915   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 59730
Mar 31, 2017 7:37:55 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
2017-03-31 19:37:56.008 plugin-container[3347:248694] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x963b, name = 'com.apple.tsm.portname'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.
2017-03-31 19:37:56.013 plugin-container[3347:248694] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x9a03, name = 'com.apple.CFPasteboardClient'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.
1490969277987   Marionette  INFO    New connections will no longer be accepted
[Child 3347] ###!!! ABORT: Aborting on channel error.: file /builds/slave/m-rel-m64-00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/glue/MessageChannel.cpp, line 2143
[Child 3347] ###!!! ABORT: Aborting on channel error.: file /builds/slave/m-rel-m64-00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/glue/MessageChannel.cpp, line 2143

org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :Selenium WebDriver — Selenium Documentation
Actual   :Selenium - Web Browser Automation
 <Click to see difference>


    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
    at test_p.test.test(test.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)


Process finished with exit code 255
```

Comment: What is your geckodriver version?

Comment: I don't have a gecko driver . I don't know how to install it?

Comment: You don't have to install just goto https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.15.0/geckodriver-v0.15.0-win32.zip and keep in a folder

Comment: How to use it? Btw, I use mac so how can I go about it sorry for the trouble!

Comment: I tried adding this // On Mac OS X.
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/Users/code/Downloads/geckodriver");

Comment: But nothing happened

Comment: Also, do I need to make any changes in the gradle file for the selenium version?

Comment: What is the problem now?

Comment: Same problem. Nothing changed

Comment: Should I post my error file here?

Comment: yeah, post it in your question.

Comment: I've updated the error statement. Please look into it @kushalツ  :)

Comment: Try commenting `assertEquals` line  and have you added Gecko Driver 0.15 / with Selenium 3.3.1 and JAVA 8

Comment: Still the problem is same!!

Comment: You  mean after commenting AssertEquals statement?

Comment: yes. Please help me solve it!

Comment: Hi Jason. When you say firefox is still navigating to 52 version, have you uninstalled 52 and installed 46? can i know if the problem resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had something similar on Linux Mint.

As it was suggested, You need to update your [Gecko Driver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases). The last version is `v0.15.0`.
After it, you have to set it's location as property, before creating FF driver:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","G:\\Selenium\\Firefox driver\\geckodriver.exe");
```

Also, you have to update `selenium-web-driver` to [latest version 3.3.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/3.3.1):

> ext.seleniumVersion = '3.3.1'

If you prefer to use not the last version for FF you need to downgrade it for your browser, manually. You can find more info here [How to downgrade Firefox version?](https://support.mozilla.org/t5/Firefox/How-to-downgrade-Firefox-version/td-p/1344068)

BTW after creating driver instance it is good to maximize the browser:

> driverInstance.manage().window().maximize();

not only implicitly wait.

Also, when you write assertion you have to write:

> assertEquals(actualResult, expectedResult);

instead of:

> assertEquals("Welcome to the CodeSolid Tutorials", driver.findElement(...));

I reviewed your code and found that your test always fails. You used incorrect `CSS` selector.

I updated it a little bit:

```
public class GitHubTest {

    private WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() {
        driver = DriverManager.getInstance();
        driver.get("https://github.com/codesolid");
    }

    @Test
    public void testFirst() throws Exception {
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("tutorials")).click();

        new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.col-11"))));

        // validate if correct page is open by title & url      
        assertEquals(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//title")).getText(), "GitHub - CodeSolid/tutorials: Tutorials");
        assertEquals(driver.getCurrentUrl(), "https://github.com/CodeSolid/tutorials");
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        DriverManager.closeQuietly();
    }
}

public class DriverManager {
    private static volatile WebDriver driverInstance;

    private DriverManager() {
    }

    public static synchronized WebDriver getInstance() {
        if (driverInstance == null) {
            switch (readBrowserType()) {
                case Firefox: {
                    driverInstance = new FirefoxDriver();
                    driverInstance.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    driverInstance.manage().window().maximize();
                    return driverInstance;
                }
```

Now test is passed:

[image]

***Additional resources:***

- [Explicit and Implicit Waits](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp)
- [XPath in Selenium WebDriver: Complete Tutorial](http://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html)

Comment: Awesome! This worked :) I had to change my gradle version and the path to the latest version :) Thanks a ton!!!!

Answer (score 2):

For me it works (also from IntelliJ IDEA) with

- Selenium 3.0.1,
- Firefox 52.0.2 64-bit on Windows 10,
- Gecko driver 0.14.0 64-bit.

System property `webdriver.gecko.driver` also needs to be set correctly, of course.

By the way, the second assertion should be changed to

```java
assertEquals(
  "Source Code for the CodeSolid Tutorials",
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("article h1")).getText()
);
```

so as to make the test pass.

Comment: Awesome! This worked :) I had to change my gradle version and the path to the latest version :) Thanks a ton!!!!  Thanks for the css selector code :) It's working now :)

Comment: I would have done that but nazar_art gave step by step explanation and it helped me solve to the problem. Sorry. I've upvoted your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

as per https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/548 & https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/526 this issue is still at large ;)

so I'd suggest you to downgrade your Gecko driver to `v0.14` or `v0.13`, if these gecko versions doesn't work with `selenium 3.3.1` then you can also try to downgrade selenium version to `selenium 3.0`.

Cheers!!